Literature suggestions: Guarantees for GPs with subset of data
I am currently trying to solve the following problem:
Given a fixed set of query points (or if possible even better: a region where I want to obtain accurate predictions), approximate the GP such that accurate predictions are obtained.
Especially, I am looking for stategies with guarantees regarding accuracy at the desired points. Hence, I do not want a global approximation of the GP, but only a local approximation that is supposed to be accurate in some region. My current approach is subselecting the datapoints based on the kernel value, i.e. neglecting datapoints that have low covariance with the desired query points? Can I somehow obtain guarantees for that?
Many thanks for any help and literature suggestions.
